# How does LUIS determine intent from inputs?

Tags: azure-language-understanding

I recently did up a basic chat bot and let my friend tested it. She entered many different gibberish, and the results from LUIS confuses me.

For example, she would enter `)(*)($*#)(!*#&$*#&$*#&)$(*)(!*)(!@*09837$)(@*#||||`, and LUIS would identify this as one of my intent that checks a database status. The only thing that I can think of is that it contains `09837`, a number, and triggers the particular intent from there. However, number entities used in the intent for checking database status is part of a composite entity (issue id). This doesn't make sense to me.

To eliminate the number entity, I shortened the query to `)(*)($*#)(!*#&$*#&$*#&)$(*)(!*)(!@*`, but it still triggers the same intent, just with no entities now.

**May I understand how does LUIS determine intents from user inputs? Do I have to add that particular user input in the `None` intent? If so, wouldn't there be too many gibberish inputs to think of to prevent such cases from happening?**

Please let me know if you need more information to answer the question! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LUIS is a natural language processor. Your example isn't natural language so you would need to either provide processing before using LUIS to turn it into natural language or use abilities in LUIS that it is not meant for -- at this time.

The NONE intent trains LUIS for all utterances that are outside the domain/scope of the app. The best place to find these are in your current utterances from customers.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. May I ask how to identify where the user input is? I am fairly new to the bot framework, and followed [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-quickstart). I will not be able to use `session.message.text` since it `session` has not yet been defined when the intents are identified.

Comment: and [this sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/intelligence-LUIS) for the LUIS part.

Comment: I think the BF 3.x code is confusing you because so much of what it does is hidden away. Please look at this sample --https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-nodejs-tutorial-build-bot-framework-sample#add-dialogs-to-handle-the-homeautomation-intents - the session.message.text is the utterance -- what the user entered in the bot -- and the args is the information back from LUIS

Comment: Thank you! I will look at it and tweak my bot :)